# Firebase Cloud Messaging not showing notification in browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman, service-worker

So I have succesfully created a service-worker and recieve a auth token when user enabled notifications permissions, and I confirmed it my Chrome browser.

I recieve the message from POSTman but I get no visible message in my browser, only in console (F12) why?

> [firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message

firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
    "placeholder"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
```

notifications.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-messaging.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
"placeholder"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

var notify = document.getElementById('dropdownMenuButton');
var timeAgoTextElement = document.getElementById('timeAgoText');

async function requestPermissionAndToken() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    try {
      const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
      console.log('Service Worker registered:', registration);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
    }
  }
  try {
    // Request permission for notifications
    await Notification.requestPermission();
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');

    // Retrieve the device token
    const token = await getToken(messaging);
    getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: ""})
    .then((currentToken) => {
      if (currentToken) {
        console.log('current token for client: ', currentToken);
      } else {
        console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error requesting permission or obtaining token:', error);
  }
}

// Function to mark the notification as clicked and save the current time in cookies
function markNotificationClicked() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('notificationClicked', 'true');
    sessionStorage.setItem('notificationTime', new Date().toString());
}

// Function to check if the notification has been clicked in the current session using cookies
function isNotificationClicked() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('notificationClicked') === 'true';
}

// Function to update the notification count
function updateNotificationCount() {
    var addNumbClass = !isNotificationClicked();
    notify.classList.toggle('add-numb', addNumbClass);
}

// Function to format time difference as "just nu," "1 dag sedan," etc.
function formatTimeDifference(timeDiff) {
    if (timeDiff < 1) {
        return "just nu";
    } else if (timeDiff === 1) {
        return "1 dag sedan";
    } else {
        return timeDiff + " dagar sedan";
    }
}

// Function to update the time display
function updateTimeAgo() {
    var notificationTime = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem('notificationTime')) || new Date();
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = Math.floor((now - notificationTime) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    timeAgoTextElement.textContent = formatTimeDifference(timeDiff);
}

// Add an event listener to the dropdown button
notify.addEventListener('click', function() {
    notify.setAttribute('data-count', '0');
    markNotificationClicked();
    updateNotificationCount();
    updateTimeAgo(); // Call the function immediately after clicking

    // Update the time every hour
    setInterval(updateTimeAgo, 1000 * 60 * 60);
});

// Initialize Bootstrap Dropdown
var dropdownElement = document.querySelector('#dropdownMenuButton');
var dropdown = new bootstrap.Dropdown(dropdownElement, {
    popperConfig: function(popperConfig) {
        popperConfig.modifiers = [
            { name: 'flip', enabled: false, options: { padding: 10 } },
            { name: 'offset', options: { offset: [0, 10] } },
            { name: 'computeStyles', options: { adaptive: false } },
            { name: 'preventOverflow', options: { padding: 10 } }
        ];
        return popperConfig;
    }
});

// Update the time immediately
updateTimeAgo();
// Update the notification count initially
updateNotificationCount();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Get the checkbox element
  const mailCheckbox = document.getElementById('dmNotification');

  // Check if the checkbox element exists
  if (mailCheckbox) {
    // Add a change event listener to the checkbox
    mailCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
      handleCheckboxChange(mailCheckbox);
    });
  } else {
    console.warn('Checkbox element not found on this page.');
  }
});

function handleCheckboxChange(checkbox) {
  // Check if notifications are supported by the browser
  if ('Notification' in window) {
    // Check if the user has granted permission for notifications
    if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
      // If the checkbox is checked, show a notification
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        showNotification('Notification Title', 'Du kommer nu att få aviseringar för privata meddelanden.');
        requestPermissionAndToken();
      } else {
        // If the checkbox is unchecked, show a different notification
        showNotification('Notification Title', 'Du har inaktiverat aviseringar för privata meddelanden.');
      }
    } else {
      // If permission is not granted, request permission
      Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
        // If permission is granted, show a notification
        if (permission === 'granted' && checkbox.checked) {
          showNotification('Notification Title', 'Du kommer nu att få aviseringar för privata meddelanden.');
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    // Browser does not support notifications
    console.error('Notifications not supported in this browser.');
  }
}

function showNotification(title, message) {
  // Implement your notification logic here
  console.log('Notification:', title, message);
}
```

Comment: Also there is no settings in my browser itself that blocks it.